# How to create a parent child hierarchy from full path

Tags: sql-server-2008, hierarchy, directory-structure

I have a column in at table stored in SQL Server 2008 containing the full paths of some documents.

I need the paths transformed into a parent child hierarchy like shown below. I need this structure because it is required of the third party software I am using it for.

How is this done most elegant?

From:

```
root/Dir1/Dir11/Dir3/Docname1.txt
root/Dir1/Dir12/Dir3/Docname2.txt
root/Dir1/Dir11/Docname3.txt
root/Dir1/Dir11/Dir31/Docname4.txt
```

To:

```
[Value]                 [Parent]
Docname1.txt            root/Dir1/Dir11/Dir3    
root/Dir1/Dir11/Dir3    root/Dir1/Dir11
root/Dir1/Dir11         root/Dir1
root/Dir1               root

Docname2.txt            root/Dir1/Dir12/Dir3
root/Dir1/Dir12/Dir3    root/Dir1/Dir12
root/Dir1/Dir12         root/Dir1
root/Dir1               root

Docname3.txt            root/Dir1/Dir11
root/Dir1/Dir11         root/Dir1
root/Dir1               root

Docname4.txt            root/Dir1/Dir11/Dir31
root/Dir1/Dir11/Dir31   root/Dir1/Dir11
root/Dir1/Dir11         root/Dir1
root/Dir1               root
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from a user on another site:

http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/100704/how-to-create-a-parent-child-hierarchy-from-full-p.html#answer-100739